# How to write math symbols in a verbatim?

Tags: math-mode, verbatim

Basically I have a section that is describing my algorithm in a pseudo code kind of way, and so I want that text to look like the verbatim text except I still want to be able to use math symbols. Is there any way to do this? Or any other hacky way to get the result?

Comment: You should consider the [`listings` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) which provides `mathescape`. This escapes to LaTeX within math, setting the symbols the way you want while still keeping the other content verbatim-like.

Comment: @Werner ive installed it and listed the package. could you kindly give me quick sample syntax for using mathescape?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) provides a `mathescape` option to escape to LaTeX within math mode (between `$`...`$`). There are other escapable options as well, details of which are contained within the [`listings` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) (section **4.14 Escaping to LaTeX**, p 39).

Here is a quick example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  mathescape
}
\begin{document}
Here is some text.
\begin{lstlisting}
Some verbatim text and $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$.
\end{lstlisting}
Here is some more text.
\begin{verbatim}
Some verbatim text and $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$.
\end{verbatim}
Some final text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: oh werner, this worked perfectly. thanks for the full answer, i have a deadline in 10 hours and ive been using latex only for an hour! thank you!!

Comment: @garciaj then I think it's not worth it using Latex, unless it's (relatively) simple.

Comment: @Manuel, Its definitely worth using Latex, it is THE best thing ive come across lately! and half my essay is filled with equations so couldnt have done it without it

Comment: @garciaj Now it's the moment. But 10 hours before a deadline… it's not the optimum time.

Comment: lstlisting does not work in xelatex. And alltt does not seem to admit Greek letters.

Comment: @jjmerelo: [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) works in XeLaTeX. If not, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: It does work, only it does funny things when Greek or other letters are included: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81674/unicode-characters-changing-order-in-listings-xetex I still have the same problem.

Comment: @jjmerelo: What about [`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb)?

Comment: It's indeed fancy, but doesn't have an option to use a font that interprets those characters correctly.

Comment: In fact, it was just a matter of adding `\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}`, that is, a monospace font that includes Greek and other letters. The default ones don't.

Answer (score 5):

In XeLaTeX, which admits typing the Unicode symbols directly, the only thing you need is to select a mono font that can display them.

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
```

And then

```
\begin{verbatim}
sin(π/3)² + cos(π/3)²
\end{verbatim}
```

will be rendered as
[image: formula correctly rendered]