# Table with margins?

Tags: spacing, formatting

I'm trying to format a table that is about 3/4 the width of the paragraph text.  I tried using tabular to do this, however it has some problems.  First, the default table extends past my documents margins.  Second, there is too much spacing in the table and it is too wide.

Does anyone know how to control the width so it's about 3/4 the width of the paragraph?  Also, how to emphasize / italicize the entire table?

Thanks!

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\lipsum
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{ c c c c c }
    <ARGUMENT> & $\equiv$ & <PROP\_PREMISE\_MAJOR> & <PROP\_PREMISE\_MINOR> & <PROP\_CONCL>
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please one problem per questio :-). For the first try to use `tabular` environment. If you will provide complete small, compilable document with your problem,  than is the most likely that you will get answer soon.

Comment: Hi thanks.  I tried tabular, however the results are still off.  It may have to do with the margins?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the `listings` package (based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149718/189932):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  mathescape
}
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sit amet convallis tortor. Etiam consequat diam in iaculis sagittis. Praesent vel scelerisque ex.
\begin{lstlisting}
  <ARGUMENT> $\equiv$ <PROP_PREMISE1> <PROP_PREMISE2> <PROP_CONCL>
  <ARGUMENT> $\equiv$ <PROP_PREMISE2> <PROP_PREMISE1> <PROP_CONCL>
\end{lstlisting}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sit amet convallis tortor. Etiam consequat diam in iaculis sagittis. Praesent vel scelerisque ex.
\begin{lstlisting}
  class Stack {
        char* v;
        int top;
        int max_size;
  public:
\end{lstlisting}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sit amet convallis tortor. Etiam consequat diam in iaculis sagittis. Praesent vel scelerisque ex.

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

EDIT: The question has changed considerably since this answer was posted, so this answer may no longer be relevant.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm trying the tabular solution.  I tried listings, however could not get the entire listing to emphasize in italics, only key words.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tabulary](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabulary), but 0.75 `linewidth` is to narrow for your five columns. You have to break the words, reduce the fontsize or increase the table lenght (or a combination):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum, tabulary}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\lipsum
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabulary}{0.75\linewidth}{CCCCC}
    <ARGUMENT> & $\equiv$ & <PROP\ \_PREMISE\ \_MAJOR> & <PROP\ \_PREMISE\ \_MINOR> & <PROP\ \_CONCL>
  \end{tabulary}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\footnotesize`and wider tabular:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum, tabulary}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

{\centering\footnotesize %put the table in a group
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{@{}CCCCC@{}}
    <ARGUMENT> & $\equiv$ & <PROP\_PREMISE\_MAJOR> & <PROP\_PREMISE\_MINOR> & <PROP\_CONCL>
  \end{tabulary}
\end{center}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your table is wider than text. Try reduce font size to `\small` and `\tabcolsep` size to 2pt:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
  \begin{tabular}{@{} c c c c c @{}}
    <ARGUMENT> & $\equiv$ & <PROP\_PREMISE\_MAJOR> & <PROP\_PREMISE\_MINOR> & <PROP\_CONCL>
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you change your original question a lot, so the first answer, which contain solution for your original question, is not related to edited anymore.  It would be better that you would ask new question ...